# List elements are NULL instead of data.frames when assigning each element at index i (R)

Tags: r, list, for-loop, null, element

I'm fairly new to R coming from other OOP languages. My job uses R for data manipulation with csv files and I'm trying to store each csv file that is read into a list of size 3.

Instead it keeps being assigned a NULL value when iterating through each csv file

```
library(tcltk)

# Should contain the prompt and require the file inputs
main <- function()
{
   # Prompt user for the files
  winDialog(type = c("ok"),
            "Select the contacts files for the academic year.\n\n
(Example: Academic year: Summer 2019 - Fall 2020)")
  
  # vector that stores each contact file
  contacts_files <<- tk_choose.files()
  
  winDialog(type = c("ok"),
            "Select the evaluations files for the academic year.\n\n
(Example: Academic year: Summer 2019 - Fall 2020)")
  
  # vector that stores each eval file
  evals_files <<- tk_choose.files()
  
  # vectors that will store each file as a dataframe
  contacts <- vector("list", length = 3);
  evals <- vector("list", length = 3);
  
  # It's assigning NULL elements to the list
  for (i in 1:length(contacts_files))
  {
    # read.csv creates a dataframe
    data <- read.csv(file = contacts_files[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
    contacts[[i]] <- data  
  }
  
  for (i in 1:length(evals_files))
  {
    data <- read.csv(file = evals_files[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    evals[[i]] <- data
  }  
}



main()
```

I checked to make sure that the "data" variable was reading the files correctly and it does. The only problem is assigning each read csv file into a list, which confuses me because you would just do

```
list[[i]] <- element value (which should be a data frame)
```

Comment: probably better/easier/more readable/faster to use something like `lapply( contacts_files, read.csv )`, which will automatically save the read data to a list of data.frames.

Comment: Further, your `main` function goes through all the trouble of generating lists of frames, and then ... discards them when it exits. The only things that survive this call to `main()` are `contacts_files` and `evals_files`, which you specifically breached the scope of the function in order to produce side-effect. If you run `main()` and then try `contacts[[1]]`, then the only thing I can think of is that you previously created `contacts <- vector('list',3)` in your global environment, forgot about it, and are wondering why the data loaded in `main` is not included in it.

Comment: also... use `<<-` only if you know what you are doing/intending... It might lead to some damn hard to read code when someone (or you yourself in a couple of months) has to review/rebuild your code...

Comment: In addition to not using `<<-` (seems like we're tag-teaming, @Wimpel) is: end the function with something like `return(list(contacts=contacts, evals=evals))` and then call `dat <- main()` so that you have everything within a `dat` object, as in `dat$contacts` ...

Comment: read *the R inferno*, chapter 6.
If you think you need  `<<-` , think again. If on reflection you still think you
need `<<- ` , think again. Only when your boss turns red with anger over you
not doing anything should you temporarily give in to the temptation.  [...] Except for a few functions that clearly have side effects, it is expected in R that a function has no side effects. A function that makes a global assignment violates this expectation. To users unfamiliar with the code (and even to the writer of the code after a few weeks) there will be an object that changes seemingly by magic.

Comment: So I used `<<-` just to see the element values in the global environment. I changed them back to `<-`. I made the main() function since I've always been taught that it's a bad idea to have a lot of variables that are global since they can easily be manipulated on accident and hard to trace, hence making my program look more like other programming languages with a `main()` function. The `lapply()` function works much better and was able to get my csv files into a list. But when does it make sense to use the global environment? For like data sheets?